# UIScrollable getChildByText doesnt scroll enough before it gives up

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am using the uiautomator tool to write some Automated Tests for my app.

Here is the code that is problematic:

```
UiScrollable appViews = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));
appViews.setAsHorizontalList(); // works on API 17+
UiObject settingsApp = appViews.getChildByText(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()), "Settings");
        settingsApp.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
```

When I run this on a KitKat phone, phone goes to home screen, then clicks "Apps" then selects "Apps tab" (this part of the code has been omitted from this post for clarity) and then it starts looking for the "Settings" icon - it scrolls horizontally once to the left, the "Downloaded" tab gets selected, then it scrolls back to the right, Settings is not there so the test fails.

I then got the phone in my hands and scrolled once more to the left and there "Settings" was.

My question is why didnt it scroll through all the pages until it found where "Settings" was?

Comment: What is **appViews**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through the documentation of UIScrollable here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/f612e6a05f47b28ae0f5715545658c08dd759dd7/uiautomator/library/src/com/android/uiautomator/core/UiScrollable.java

And I found this method:

```
scrollBackward()
```

So I decided to take care of the problem on my own this way:

```
    boolean settingsFound = false;
    while(!settingsFound) {
        appViews.scrollBackward();
        try {
            UiObject settingsApp = appViews.getChildByText(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()), "Settings", true);
            settingsApp.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
            settingsFound = true;
        } catch (Exception e){  
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

This code kept scrolling to the right until "Settings" was visible and then clicked on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the maximum number of swipes that suits your needs via [UiScrollable.setMaxSearchSwipes()](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiScrollable.html#setMaxSearchSwipes(int)), which adjusts the number of scrolls allowed when performing a scroll action in search of a child element.

Comment: The default is 55, it did 2